# Prefetch object not working with order_by queryset

Tags: python, django, query-optimization

Using Django 11 with PostgreSQL db. I have the models as shown below. I'm trying to prefetch a related queryset, using the `Prefetch` object and `prefetch_related` without assigning it to an attribute.

```
class Person(Model):
    name = Charfield()

    @property
    def latest_photo(self):
        return self.photos.order_by('created_at')[-1]

class Photo(Model):
    person = ForeignKey(Person, related_name='photos')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


first_person = Person.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('photos', queryset=Photo.objects.order_by('created_at'))).first()

first_person.photos.order_by('created_at') # still hits the database
first_person.latest_photo # still hits the database
```

In the ideal case, calling `person.latest_photo` will not hit the database again. This will allow me to use that property safely in a list display. 
However, as noted in the comments in the code, the prefetched queryset is not being used when I try to get the latest photo. Why is that?

**Note:** I've tried using the `to_attr` argument of `Prefetch` and that seems to work, however, it's not ideal since it means I would have to edit `latest_photo` to try to use the prefetched attribute.

Comment: Calling `order_by('created_at')` in the `latest_photo` method creates a new queryset so the prefetched objects are not used. Another approach to fetch the latest photo would be to use a [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

Comment: Is there no way to prefetch with order_by ? Also, could you elaborate how it would look like to prefetch with a subquery?

Comment: I’ve linked to the subquery docs for you, I can’t write the query off the top of my head. Yes, you can use `order_by` in `prefetch`. The problem is that you use a different/additional `order_by` in your `latest_photo` method.

Comment: If I wanted to you use the result of the initially prefetched order_by, how would I go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with slicing, it creates a different query.

You can work around it like this:

```
    ...

    @property
    def latest_photo(self):
        first_use_the_prefetch = list(self.photos.order_by('created_at'))
        then_slice = first_use_the_prefetch[-1]
        return then_slice
```

And in case you want to try, it is not possible to use slicing inside the Prefetch(query=...no slicing here...) (there is a wontfix feature request for this somewhere in Django tracker).